# NativeCallableAttribute missing in .Net Core application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, coreclr

I found this implementation of [NativeCallableAttribute](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/NativeCallableAttribute.cs) in coreclr repository on github. It looks like it was added 2 years ago and you can find unit tests showing that it works just like [Unmanaged exports for .Net Framework](https://github.com/3F/DllExport).

I've created a new .Net core 2.0 project and there is no `NativeCallableAttribute` present in `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace. Is there some nuget package I have to add to use this class? I've tried nuget package `System.Runtime.InteropServices` but still the attribute is missing.

Comment: It is not equivalent.  It is merely a convenient substitute for Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(), which gets too many programmers in trouble because they forget to keep the delegate referenced.  What you can't get is the DLL entrypoint, the "unmanaged export".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NativeCallableAttribute` resides in `System.Private.CoreLib` assembly. Just reference it from you project and add `using` directive for `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

**UPDATE:**

> Where do I get System.Private.CoreLib? Cannot find it on nuget and
>   AddReference dialog in VisualStudio does not have it for my .Net Core
>   project.

I have added assembly reference with ReSharper. You could do the same by adding following section to your csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Private.CoreLib">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Where do I get `System.Private.CoreLib`? Cannot find it on nuget and `AddReference` dialog in VisualStudio does not have it for my `.Net Core` project.